# Cellspacing and cellpadding doesn't apply to tables in WYSIWYG editor in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, static-content

In one of my client's websites(Magento CE 1.9.2.4), the product description needs to have a table structured content with `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` applied.

Now when he tries to apply that style to editor from code and then he switches to UI view and then back to HTML Code view then the added `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` gets removed automatically.

Now he needs to apply those two properties badly, so anyone can suggest a way around this, is this an editor limitation in Magento 1.x versions ?

Answer (score 0):

The magento wysiwyg editor will skip the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` and the quickest way to resolve this problem is use the inline style.

you can use either of below formats:

```
<td style="padding: 20px">
```

or in your css:

```
table td {
    padding: 20px;
}
```